# Is it possible to pass in the session as a variable like in Python for PHP?

Tags: php, python, session

So I've been working on porting a python tester to PHP, but I'm fairly new to PHP still. I understand there is a session command within PHP, and I've read the documentation as well as other questions that have come up here in stackoverflow that are close to it, but not quite what I'm looking for.

So my question is whether if there is something similar to *sess = requests.Session()* from python to PHP, i.e. is there something I could pass in just like I did in python that can occur also in PHP?

EDIT: So I've re-read the documentations for both the python Request package and Sessions for PHP. And I think the meat of my question is if there is a way to have a session object in PHP that holds persistent parameters across POST and GET Request? And to further explain, my main problem is that I have certain POST and GET endpoints that require a login, but even after using the login POST first, I still receive a 401 error code after.

Example Code:
$current->httpPost($accountLoginURL, $accountLoginPostData);
$current->httpPost($followFriend, $followFriendData);

And even after the first line gives me a 200. The second gives me a 401.

Comment: `requests.Session` is a way of creating a group of related client-side requests. It sounds like what you're looking for is a server-side identifier for a given client's session, which is a completely different thing. Can you show us some stripped-down example Python code, and describe what it does, and ideally give us your PHP equivalent with a pointer to the part you're stuck on?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign to and read anything you want from the $_SESSION array. It's just a regular array like any other in PHP, except for two things:

a) It's a superglobal
b) **IF** you've called `session_start()`, then PHP will auto-populate the array from whatever's in session storage (files, db, etc...), and auto-save the contents of the array upon script exit or calling `session_write_close()`.